# Printing linked list structure C

Tags: c, list, printing

So, recently I had to create a linked list structure and I think got a function of creating it to work (hopefully), but now I have such simple problem as printing it into the console. I dont know whether there is something wrong with my structure that I created, or I do something wrong with printing. I would appreciate if somebody could find what is wrong with my code:

```
struct z { int a; struct z *next; };
struct z *head, *node, *next;
int data, x = 1;

int CreateList() {
    printf("Enter 0 to end\n");
    printf("Enter data no. %d: ", x);
    x++;
    scanf("%d", &data);
    if (data == 0) return 0;
    head = (struct z *)malloc(sizeof(struct z));
    if (head == NULL) { printf("Error creating head"); return 0; }
    node = head;
    node->a = data;
    node->next = NULL;
    while (data) {
        next = (struct z *)malloc(sizeof(struct z));
        if (next == NULL) { printf("Error creating next node no. %d", x); return 0;}
        node = next;
        printf("Enter data no. %d: ", x);
        x++;
        scanf("%d", &data);
        node->a = data;
        node->next = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}


int main() {
    CreateList();
    node = head;
    while (node != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", node->a);
        node = node->next; //<=== crash on this line
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My output is always just the first entered int and then it all crashes on the marked line.

Comment: What was the input, output and expected output?

Comment: `node=next;` --> `node->next=next; node=next;`  Maybe other things too   A lot depends on input - which is not posted.

Comment: function collects int data pieces, puts them into "a" variable and saves to the node, then creates new one, and repeats. The output that I want is all data pieces printed out in the order that they were put into the linked list.

Comment: Posting the input is more useful than describing the input.

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C.

Comment: Can't really post the input, as the function takes input from user. Problem is that my function crashes on the one of last lines of printing.

Answer (score 1):

Your `main` loop uses the wrong variable:

```
int main(){
    CreateList();
    node = head;
    while (next != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", node->a);
        node = node->next; //<=== crash on this line
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You should instead use `node`:

```
int main(){
    CreateList();
    node = head;
    while (node != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", node->a);
        node = node->next; //<=== crash on this line
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Incidentally, `head`, `node` and `next` should be local variables, and `head` should be returned by `CreateList()`.

`CreateList()` does not actually create the list correctly: nodes are not linked to the list as they are created, only the first node is stored in `head`.

Here is a corrected version that returns the list and the corresponding `main` function:

```
struct z { int a; struct z *next; };

struct z *CreateList(void) {
    struct z *head, *node, *next;
    int data, x = 1;

    printf("Enter 0 to end\n");
    printf("Enter data no. %d: ", x);
    x++;
    if (scanf("%d", &data) != 1 || data == 0)
        return NULL;
    head = malloc(sizeof(struct z));
    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("Error creating head");
        return NULL;
    }
    node = head;
    node->a = data;
    node->next = NULL;
    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter data no. %d: ", x);
        x++;
        if (scanf("%d", &data) != 1 || data == 0)
            break;
        next = malloc(sizeof(struct z));
        if (next == NULL) {
            printf("Error creating next node no. %d", x - 1);
            return NULL;
        }
        node->next = next;
        node = next;
        node->a = data;
        node->next = NULL;
    }
    return head;
}

int main(void) {
    struct z *head = CreateList();
    struct z *node;
    for (node = head; node != NULL; node = node->next) {
        printf("%d ", node->a);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Those are good tips, however returning those variables or simply not using a function and just code to generate the list didnt work and I still get a crash on the same line as before.

Comment: @Thirstix In addition to the fix of chux comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the global variables. Make them in the function, at least the node and the next. Create these on demand, for when you are actually adding the values. As a final tip, for this case, a do-while loop would make your code look cleaner than what it is right now, definitely you'd have less code repeat.